# DB connection failed after update to Java 8 for Play 2.3 application

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3, playframework-2.4

I got an error after upgrading to Java 8. I didn't change anything from applicatoin.conf. Play is still 2.3. I am planing to upgrade to 2.4 later.

This is my db configuration:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/prdata"



[info] ! create
[error]    anon$1: : Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]  (Configuration.scala:94)
[error] play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94)
[error] play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:743)
[error] play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:247)
[error] play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:238)
[error] play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.onStart(DB.scala:238)
[error] play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
[error] play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
[error] play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
[error] play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
[error] play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
[error] play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
[error] play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
[error] play.api.test.PlayRunners$class.running(Helpers.scala:48)
[error] play.api.test.Helpers$.running(Helpers.scala:403)
[error] play.api.test.WithApplication.around(Specs.scala:23)
[error] play.api.test.WithApplication.delayedInit(Specs.scala:20)
```

Comment: Are you sure your Postgres local instance is started, listening on port `5432` and that `prdata` db exists and accessible for these credentials ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Its localhost problem. Once I changed to 127.0.0.1, it works now.